# ngTableParams Pagination with $http.get

Tags: angularjs, http, pagination, ngtable

Working on an AngularJS project and I've ran into the following problem:

When using locally stored / hard coded data, the pagination works fine.
When using remotely stored data, the pagination does not work properly.

I have searched quite a bit, but couldn't find the solution to my problem, so here are the code snippits:

The HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ngTableCtrl">
    <p><strong>Pagina:</strong> {{tableParams.page()}}</p>
    <p><strong>Aantal weergegeven:</strong> {{tableParams.count()}}</p>

    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped" template-pagination="custom/pager">
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
            <td data-title="'Name'">{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td data-title="'City'">{{x.City}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Country'">{{x.Country}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="custom/pager">
        <ul class="pager ng-cloak">
            <li ng-repeat="page in pages"
                ng-class="{'disabled': !page.active, 'previous': page.type == 'prev', 'next': page.type == 'next'}"
                ng-show="page.type == 'prev' || page.type == 'next'" ng-switch="page.type">
                <a ng-switch-when="prev" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&laquo; Previous</a>
                <a ng-switch-when="next" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">Next &raquo;</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" ng-class="{'active':params.count() == 2}" ng-click="params.count(2)" class="btn btn-default">2</button>
                    <button type="button" ng-class="{'active':params.count() == 5}" ng-click="params.count(5)" class="btn btn-default">5</button>
                    <button type="button" ng-class="{'active':params.count() == 10}" ng-click="params.count(10)" class="btn btn-default">10</button>
                    <button type="button" ng-class="{'active':params.count() == 15}" ng-click="params.count(15)" class="btn btn-default">15</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
app.controller('ngTableCtrl2', function ($scope, $http, $filter, ngTableParams) {

    $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php')
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1, // show first page
        count: 5, // count per page
        sorting: {
            name: 'asc' // initial sorting
        }
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});
```

The webpage ( live version: http://178.62.232.175:8080/STANDARD/#/app/table/data ) shows all results in the first table (remote, from $http.get), whilst the second table, shows only the set results?! (2, 5, 10, 15)
The code is identical, except for:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
```

used to display remote data and is replaced by:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in $data">
```

to display raw data as such:

```
var data = [{
Name: "Alfreds Futterkiste", City: "Berlin", Country: "Germany"},{
Name: "Ana Trujillo Emparedados", City: "México D.F.", Country: "Mexico"},{
Name: "Antonio Moreno Taquería", City: "México D.F.", Country: "Mexico"},{
Name: "Around the Horn", City: "London", Country: "UK"},{
Name: "B's Beverages", City: "London", Country: "UK"},{
Name: "Berglunds snabbköp", City: "Luleå", Country: "Sweden"},{
Name: "Blauer See Delikatessen", City: "Mannheim", Country: "Germany"},{
Name: "Blondel père et fils", City: "Strasbourg", Country: "France"},{
Name: "Bólido Comidas preparadas", City: "Madrid", Country: "Spain"},{
Name: "Bon app", City: "Marseille", Country: "France"},{
Name: "Bottom-Dollar Marketse", City: "Tsawassen", Country: "Canada"},{
Name: "Cactus Comidas para llevar", City: "Buenos Aires", Country: "Argentina"}
];
```

The pagination of the second table works as it should. What must I edit to make it work with remote data?

Comment: to make it work, you need to refresh data from server side on click on prev/next or on page size change, i dont see that part of code here

Comment: @entre | Could you please explain what you mean by that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all your code is using the local data array as a source in ngTables `getData` callback and it is not clear what you are presenting as a comparison since you did not actually try [AJAX Data Loading](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/6) from the official examples .

Instead I would expect it to have an api call to the server using $http.get.

Remember for server side paging to work you must update the total count each time you query for data because they may have changed. Also you will have to consider a server side solution for sorting as well.

Here is a working sample using the github api as a test service.

```js
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, ngTableParams) {
  $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 5,
            }, {
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    var page = params.page();
                    var size = params.count();
                    var testUrl = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories';
                    var search = {
                      q: 'angular',
                      page: page,
                      per_page: size
                    }
                    $http.get(testUrl, { params: search, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
                         .then(function(res) {
                            params.total(res.data.total_count);
                            $defer.resolve(res.data.items);
                        }, function(reason) {
                            $defer.reject();
                        }
                    );
                },
            });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.3.3/ng-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.3.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="main"  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr ng-repeat="repo in $data">
            <td data-title="'id'">{{repo.id}}</td>
            <td data-title="'name'">{{repo.name}}</td>
            <td data-title="'owner'">{{repo.owner.login}}</td>
        </tr>
</table> 
<div>
```

Comment: I modified my code to look exactly like yours, but now it's just giving me nothing. http://178.62.232.175:8080/STANDARD/#/app/table/data < live version

Comment: please update your question to include what you are currently trying and fails. Otherwise I cannot guess. The link you are giving does not help a lot since it is failing with errors.

Comment: @DeKnarf I peeked in your code and you have several syntax errors in your javascript file ngTableCtrl.js. Check the example above again. change line 27 from `var page - params.page();` to `var page = params.page(); `and line 42 from `};` to `);`

Comment: Thank you, that does work. Now I 'should' be able to work from that!