# ngTable with data from web api not working

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ngTable for AngularJS and geting the data from a web api. The problem start when I tried to use the filters in the table.

If I do it this way, the table is filled with the data, but the filters don't works:

```
$scope.clientesTable = new NgTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 10
        }, {
                getData: function (params) {
                    var clientes = clientesService.getAll(baseUrl);
                    clientes.then(function (data) {
                        $scope.clientesTableData = data.data;
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log("Error: " + error);
                    });
                }

            });
```

In the documentation the code is something like this:

```
$scope.clientesTable = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10
            }, {
                    getData: function (params) {
                        var clientes = clientesService.getAll(baseUrl);
                        clientes.then(function (data) {
                              params.total(data.inlineCount);
                              return data.results;
                        }, function (error) {
                            console.log("Error: " + error);
                        });
                    }

                });
```

Doing it this way, I don't see the data in the frontend. If a look for data in clientesTable:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Response from web api:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a console.log after clientes.then(function (data) { ...

Comment: @Gerfried showing the data?

Comment: yes, do you receive any data from your service. Is the structure data.data?

Comment: yes, the data is okey. If i asigne data.data to a var in $scope, then i can see it in the front end. The problem is when i use return data.data just like it is in the documentation.

Comment: @GuidoCaffa Probably you have to write a return statement before clientes.then()

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide `return` keyword before `clientes.then()` inside getData method.

Answer (score 0):

If I look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629034/3177115 I see that `NgTableParams` is used differently. You need to use it with a promise which returns the data back into the NgTableParams object.

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1, count: 5,
        }, {
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                $http.get(testUrl, { params: params })
                     .then(function(res) {
                        $defer.resolve(res.data.items);
                    }, function(reason) {
                        $defer.reject();
                    }
                );
            },
        });
```

Please see the full example for details, I have simplified the example a bit for better understanding.

**EDIT:**

I think the API of ng-tables has changed - it does not expect a deferer any more. 
Looking now at your first code example again (which you say it works) I see why the filter is not working: You do not pass the filter information back to your service.

The ng-table docs say: http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-filtering-basic

> Got a getData function? In this case you'll need to apply the values
>   from NgTableParams.filters() to the data you want to display in your
>   table. This is typically the case when the data is being fetched from
>   the server

I don't know your service, but can you add the filter params to the service call?

```
var clientes = clientesService.getAll(baseUrl, params._params)
```

Btw: the docs of ng-table are a nightmare - all samples inherit from each other and use directives and injects.

Comment: Doing it that way i have this error: TypeError: "params is undefined". I can't find why I have this error, I was using parameters in the code and I wasn't having this problem.